# Use C# or VBA to call Jersey JAX-RS REST Webservice

Tags: java, c#, excel, web-services, vba

I have a Jersey REST webservice and it works fine with java client. Now I'm wondering is it possible to use C# or VBA to call this webservice? Sorry I am new to C#/VBA. I am trying to create a add-in for excel. As far as I know I can use these two to create add-in. So my questions are:

1. What's the best way to create add-in in excel for getting/uploading data? Is Java possible? Or should I use C#?
2. If I use C#, is it possible to call java webservice in C#? I want to upload data via this webservice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that can build an HTTP request matching the input expected for your Jersey REST service will work. JAX-WS and JAX-RS services are going to be exposed as agnostic access points for anything which can send an XML/JMS or HTTP request. You can confirm this by simply opening the endpoint in your web browser and trying to submit some GET requests that way.

Answer (score 0):

That is the beauty of web services, they SHOULD be language agnostic. Basically you are just calling a url to return you some xml/json data which c# can handle.